# Random pairs of all values in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, random

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'lat' : range(0,8),
                    'name' : ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b']})
df
```

Output is:

```
    lat name
0   0   a
1   1   a
2   2   a
3   3   a
4   4   b
5   5   b
6   6   b
7   7   b
```

Now, what I would like to do is within each name type, create random pairings and add them together.  However, all rows need to be a part of a random pairing.

So the ideal output would look something like:

```
  name  pairing sum
0   a   0,3      3
1   a   2,1      3
2   b   6,4      10
3   b   7,5      12
```

However, it's important that no a's are paired with b's, and that all values are in exactly one pair.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to create a *pair* column as a group variable, and then aggregate the results group by *name* and *pair*:

```
import pandas as pd
# use random permutation with modulo division to generate the pair group variable
def random_pairs(x):
    return pd.np.random.permutation(pd.np.arange(len(x)))//2
​
df['pair'] = df.groupby('name').lat.transform(random_pairs)

(df.groupby(['name', 'pair']).lat
 .agg({'pairing': lambda x: ', '.join(x.astype(str)), 'sum': 'sum'})
 .reset_index('pair', drop=True).reset_index())

#name  sum  pairing
#0  a    1     0, 1
#1  a    5     2, 3
#2  b    9     4, 5
#3  b   13     6, 7
```